# Determinant's properties and self adjoint operator

Tags: matrices, determinant, adjoint-operators

I noticed that, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, holds the following identity:

$$
   \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix}
    <LX|X> & <LX|Y> \\
    <LY|X> & <LY|Y>\\
    \end{pmatrix} = \mathrm{det}(L)\mathrm{det}\begin{pmatrix}
    <X|X> & <X|Y> \\
    <Y|Y> & <Y|Y>\\
    \end{pmatrix} 
$$

where $L$ is a real and symmetric operator, $<X|Y>$ is the scalar product and $X$, $Y$ are independent vectors.
I prove the equality writing explicitly the determinant of both sides, and it was very tedious. The question is:

Does this equality hold also in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
And how can I prove this equality in a better, quickly way?

Thanks

P.S. 
I think it is not true that $A = LS$ where $A$ is the first matrix and $S=\begin{pmatrix}
    <X|X> & <X|Y> \\
    <Y|Y> & <Y|Y>\\
    \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product, there exists a positive definite matrix $P$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle=x^TPy$ for every pair of vectors $x$ and $y$. It follows that
$$
S_L:=\pmatrix{\langle Lx_1,x_1\rangle&\cdots& \langle Lx_1,x_n\rangle\\
\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\langle Lx_n,x_1\rangle&\cdots& \langle Lx_n,x_n\rangle}
=\pmatrix{x_1^TL^TPx_1&\cdots&x_1^TL^TPx_n\\
\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
x_n^TL^TPx_1&\cdots&x_n^TL^TPx_n}
=(LX)^TPX.
$$
Therefore $\det(S_L)=\det(L)\det(X^TPX)=\det(L)\det(S_I)$.

Comment: Perfect:) Thanks